# Possible to make an IntelliJ IDEA Run/Debug Config where the contents of the active editor window|tab are passed as a script parameter?

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone know if there is a way to pass the contents of the Active editor window/tab in IntelliJ IDEA CE 11.x as a parameter to a Groovy script being executed as a Run/Debug configuration? I was hoping IDEA would have some concept of internal environment variables that might allow this (such as $_ACTIVE_EDITOR), but I have been unable to find anything that might help.

Essentially my use case is to take the contents of current window/tab and run a custom tool against it - the custom tool is a groovy script that accepts a String as an argument.

Comment: I believe something like that can be done by developing an IntelliJ plugin

Comment: I just started looking into that, but I was hoping to avoid having to dive that deep.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some wrapper that will read a file into a string and then call your script. IDEA External Tools can pass current file name to this wrapper. There is also a macro for the selected text.

Instead of the external tool you can install and use [Batch Scripts Support](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=6501) plug-in or [Bash Support](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=4230). They provide run configurations for the command line tools.

Also check [Shell Process](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&pluginId=6001) plug-in, it claims to run external apps with the editor selection.